# java identifiers

Tags: java

Everywhere is said that a Java identifier can start with all characters (but not digits) including `$` and `_`

but I noticed that methods like `isJavaIdentifierStart` returns true also for other chars
like `§`, `£`, `€` etc

Is however correct starting an identifier with there characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `isJavaIdentifierStart` returns true for it, then *by definition*, it's a valid Java identifier starting character, because that's [how the specification defines it](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8):

> Identifier:
>   
>       IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
>   
> IdentifierChars:
>   
>       JavaLetter
>   
>       IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit
>   
> JavaLetter:
>   
>       any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)
>   
> JavaLetterOrDigit:
>   
>       any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
>   
> ...
>   
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

[The method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28char%29) means what it says.

It returns false for `§`, because it's not a letter, [`Character.getType('§')`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) is not [`Character.LETTER_NUMBER`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#LETTER_NUMBER), it's not a currency symbol, and it's not a connecting punctuation character.

It is true for the two currency symbols, because that is a specific criterion.